# Getting `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable` Error while initializing variables in tensor flow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

While I'm trying to initialize the variable in tensor flow, I'm getting above exception. Below is the code. Can someone help on this?

```
import tensorflow as tf


node1 = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
node2 = tf.constant(4.0) # also tf.float32 implicitly


print(node1, node2)
init_g = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init_l = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_g)
sess.run(init_l)
print(sess.run([node1, node2]))
node3 = tf.add(node1, node2)

print(node3) #prints type in tensorflow
print(sess.run([node3]))


node4 = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
print(sess.run([node4]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to me when I initialize the global variables and creating new variables / operations after

try this

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    node1 = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
    node2 = tf.constant(4.0) # also tf.float32 implicitly
    node3 = tf.add(node1, node2)
    node4 = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    print(node1, node2)
    print(sess.run([node1, node2]))
    print(node3) #prints type in tensorflow
    print(sess.run([node3]))
    print(sess.run([node4]))
```

The idea is to build the computations first, of course that includes the variables, then call the operation that you need by using `sess.run()`